# Validate array response http GET Rest-Assured

Tags: arrays, json, api, validation, rest-assured

I am using Rest-Assured for API test. This API returns an array, for that of JSON I am able to extract the body and validate, how do I validate the body of this object as it is an array?

```
[
    {
        "FirstName": "Kehinde",
        "LastName": "Adeoya",
        "ProfilePicture": "",
        "Accounts": []
    }
]
```

For that of JSON I can write this:

```
response.then().body("", equalsTo(""));
```

Comment: This link might help you. FYR 
 http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Hamcrest/article.html

Comment: and which values of the array you want to validate?

Comment: For converting response to JSON array you can use below snippet and iterate over it and assert which values you want to validate.                           
 JSONArray JSONResponseBodyArray = new JSONArray(response.body().asString());